# How to add local repository in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. I am trying to add a local repository by using management console.

[image]

But every time i try to do this, i am getting the following error.

[image]

**Ultimate Goal:**

I want to add this local repository because i want to install WSO2 Deployment Synchronizer feature in my ESB. I am making a clustered environment. To install any new feature, you must have a repository added. So please help me i think i am missing something in the picture here ..

Answer (score 0):

Deployment synchronizer is available by default in all products. You need to configure relevant svn url parameters in the carbon.xml